# mapping dictonary a key with multiple values to json in python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I am trying to map a dictionary with one key that has multiple values into python. Here is what I got.

```
import json

list =['abe','matt','roscoe']
key="name"
nodes={}
nodes.setdefault(key,list)
['abe', 'matt', 'roscoe']

json_nodes =json.dumps(nodes)
json_nodes
'{"name": ["abe", "matt", "roscoe"]}'
```

But I would like to have a json file similar to this
[
 {
        "name": "abe"
    },
    {
        "name": "matt"
    },
    {
        "name": "roscoe"
    }
]

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a list of names, like this

```
>>> names = ['abe', 'matt', 'roscoe']
```

You just need to iterate the names, and create a new dictionary on every iteration to get the list of dictionaries, like this

```
>>> json.dumps([{"name": name} for name in names])
[{"name": "abe"}, {"name": "matt"}, {"name": "roscoe"}]
```

Here,

```
[{"name": name} for name in names]
```

is called *List Comprehension*. It is a convenient technique to generate new lists. In our case, we iterate over `names` with `for name in names`. On every iteration, `name` will have the current name corresponding to the iteration and we create a new dictionary with `{"name": name}`.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know of any resources where I can get better with  iterating dictionaries and list? Is it just practice?

Comment: @user3426338 You can read about List, Set and Dictionary comprehensions. They will come in handy often and they are preferred way to program in Python.